# Google Map V3 Constants as Variables

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the example below I am trying to update the map type depending on the value of the selected option type.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to load the `maptype` into the `google.maps.MapTypeId` which is frustrating. I have tried it as a string as well as `var gmapsMapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.++maptype;` and I feel I am missing something here.

**HTML**

```
<select id="maptype" name="maptype">
    <option selected="selected" value="RoadMap">Road Map</option>
    <option value="Satellite">Satellite</option>
    <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
    <option value="Terrain">Terrain</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var maptype = $('#maptype>option:selected').val().toUpperCase();
var gmapsMapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.+maptype;
map.setMapTypeId(gmapsMapType);
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [subscript-notation](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html):

```
google.maps.MapTypeId[maptype];
```

Comment: +1 you're right.  In my answer I've calling the initialize method each time.  Whereas your approach I love it.  I have created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/3150/) for your answer.  Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the **`mapOptions`**, it is an object which holds the following attributes.

```
center: N
mapTypeId: "roadmap" //lowercase 
zoom: 8
```

The mapTypeId is of lowercase and hence you can simple use like

```
function initialize() {
    var maptype = $('#maptype>option:selected').val().toLowerCase();
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.565529, -80.197645);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: maptype
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$("#maptype").change(function () {
    initialize();
})
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/3149/)